# Trying to find/remember an HTML-writing macro (Emacs?)

Tags: emacs, html, macros

There was a keyboard macro I saw once for writing HTML (and perhaps XML), so that if you typed something like:

```
a.foo#bar
```

it would turn that into something like:

```
<a class="foo" id="bar">
```

I think it was an Emacs package, but it may have been for Textmate or some other editor.  (I don't think it was a command-line utility: I know about HAML, which is neat, but that's not it.  The expansion happened right away, not after running a command.)

Can anyone find this for me?  Typing in variations and combinations of "emacs", "macro", and "html" in google just isn't working very well for me today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding), which uses CSS-style shorthand for writing HTML, and is available as a plug-in for various text editors.

See the [official site](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding) for more information and downloads.